# UTC to local method in DateTimeZone of Joda-Time to Java 8

Tags: java-8, jodatime, java-time

We are changing Joda-Time API's to Java 8 time API's. In Joda-Time I have used:

```
DateTimeZone.convertLocalToUTC(this.getMillis(), true);
DateTimeZone.convertUTCToLocal(long millis);
```

Can any one tell me equivalent methods in Java 8?

**Edited**

**convertLocalToUTC**

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
DateTime jodadatetime = new DateTime();
long utcTime = dateTimeZone.convertLocalToUTC(jodadatetime .getMillis(), true);
System.out.println(jodadatetime);

DateTimeZone dateTimeZone1 = DateTimeZone.UTC;
System.out.println(new DateTime(utcTime, dateTimeZone1));
```

**Output**

> 2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30
>      2017-08-09T06:27:57.508Z

**ConvertUtcToLocal**

```
long utctolocal = dateTimeZone.convertUTCToLocal(jodadatetime.getMillis());
System.out.println("utc to local : " + new DateTime(utctolocal, dateTimeZone1));
```

**Output**

> 2017-08-09T17:27:57.508Z

Comment: `convertUTCToLocal` takes a `long` as parameter, not a `DateTimeZone`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Hugo sorry my mistake

Comment: What's the default timezone?

Comment: @Hugo [Asia/Calcutta]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your original date is `2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30`, then you want 2 things:

1. `convertLocalToUTC`: get `2017-08-09T06:27:57.508Z`. This is a little bit tricky:

The original date is `2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30`, which is equivalent in UTC to `2017-08-09T11:57:57.508Z`. What this method does is to convert this to the same local date and time but at the Calcutta timezone, and then you're printing it in UTC. In short:

- original date is `2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30`

  - in UTC, that's the same as `2017-08-09T11:57:57.508Z`
- `convertLocalToUTC` converts this to `2017-08-09T11:57:57.508+05:30` (same date and time, but in Calcutta timezone)

  - and that's the same as `2017-08-09T06:27:57.508Z`

To do this in Java 8, you can do:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta");
// original date 2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30
Instant i = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30")
    // convert to UTC (2017-08-09T11:57:57.508Z)
    .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    // convert to same local time in Calcutta
    .withZoneSameLocal(zone)
    // back to UTC
    .toInstant();
System.out.println(i.toEpochMilli() + "=" + i);
```

Output:

> 1502260077508=2017-08-09T06:27:57.508Z

2. `convertUTCToLocal`: get `2017-08-09T17:27:57.508Z` - the same date (2017-08-09) and time (17:27:57.508) but in UTC.

It's similar:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta");
// original date 2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30
ZonedDateTime z = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30")
    // convert to a ZonedDateTime in Calcutta (2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30[Asia/Calcutta])
    .atZoneSameInstant(zone)
    // convert to same local time in UTC
    .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(z.toInstant().toEpochMilli() + "=" + z);
```

Output:

> 1502299677508=2017-08-09T17:27:57.508Z

---

You can also get the dates from the millis value.

For case 1:

```
// millis for original joda date: jodadatetime.getMillis() (1502279877508 = 2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30)
long millisFromJoda = 1502279877508L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisFromJoda)
    // convert to UTC (2017-08-09T11:57:57.508Z)
    .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    // convert to same local time in Calcutta
    .withZoneSameLocal(zone)
    // back to UTC
    .toInstant();
System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli() + "=" + instant);
```

Output:

> 1502260077508=2017-08-09T06:27:57.508Z

You can convert the `Instant` to another types if you want:

```
// convert to ZonedDateTime in UTC
ZonedDateTime zd = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// convert to OffsetDateTime in UTC
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Both will be `2017-08-09T06:27:57.508Z`.

And for case 2:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisFromJoda)
    // convert to a ZonedDateTime in Calcutta (2017-08-09T17:27:57.508+05:30[Asia/Calcutta])
    .atZone(zone)
    // convert to same local time in UTC
    .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() + "=" + zdt);
```

Output:

> 1502299677508=2017-08-09T17:27:57.508Z

Comment: For case 1 with millis I want ZonedDatetime/OffsetDateTime rather than instant. when I try to change the instant to Zoned/OffsetDateTime time is changing

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code snippet that may help you get started:

```
LocalDateTime yourLocalTime = ...
long utc = yourLocalTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
```

or as you used `strict = true` the following:

```
long utc = ZonedDateTime.ofStrict(yourLocalTime, ZoneOffset.UTC, ZoneId.of("Z")).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Converting back is similar:

```
LocalDateTime yourUtcTime = ...
long localTimeInMillis = yourUtcTime.toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset() /* or: yourLocalTime.getOffset() */).toEpochMilli();
```

If you don't need the millis, but want to work with the DateTime-classes instead, you may want to use `ZonedDateTime` instead?

Creating a `LocalDateTime` from millis could be done as follows:

```
LocalDateTime yourLocalDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisAsLong).atZone(/* your desired zone here */).toLocalDateTime();
```

where zone id could be `ZoneId.of("Z")`, `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, etc.

Comment: In my code LocaltoUtc conversion gives **2017-08-09T06:50:15.644Z** but I have used your code **ZonedDateTime.ofStrict(yourLocalTime, ZoneOffset.UTC, ZoneId.of("Z"))** it gives **2017-08-09T17:50:15.582Z**